# re.sub() substitute between through multiple lines

Tags: python, regex

I want to substitute text between ")" and "String" and also include the identifiers in the output, my code works if the required text was in one line, but it doesn't work for multiple lines.

```
import re

s = """
 text1) text2 
 TEXT3 text4

    """


if re.findall(r'(?<=\))\s.*(.*?)(?=\s*TEXT3)',s,re.S):
            test= re.sub(r'(?<=\))\s.*(?=\bTEXT3)',' ',s)
            print(test)
else:
  print("Not Found")
```

My required output is this:

```
text1) TEXT3 text4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optimized approach:

The pattern `\)[^)]+(?=\bTEXT3)` is more performant than `(?<=\))(.*?)(?=\bTEXT3)`.

```
import re

s = """
 text1) text2 
 TEXT3 text4

    """

res = re.sub(r'\)[^)]+(?=\bTEXT3)', ') ', s, re.M)
print(res)
```

The output:

```
text1) TEXT3 text4
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew , the further possible optimization is welcome (if exists).

Answer (score 0):

Use `flags=re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL`

**Ex:**

```
import re

s = """
text1) text2 
TEXT3 text4
   """

test= re.sub(r'(?<=\))(.*?)(?=\bTEXT3)',' ',s, flags=re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
print(test) #text1) TEXT3 text4
```